# ¿Se puede abortar un Handler Looper?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

En mi aplicación tengo código que detiene la app por unos segundos y cuando se alcanza ese tiempo, se ejecuta una acción. ¿Es posible abortar ese momento en el que se detiene la app? Este es el código que la detiene:

```
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                    // Funciones que se ejecutan pasado el tiempo
                  
                }, 3000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma de "abortar" un handler es usando el método del handler [removeCallbacksAndMessages()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object)).

Ejemplo:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(() -> /*  // Funciones que se ejecutan pasado el tiempo callMyMethod()*/, 3000);

// Cuando necesites cancelar, usa:
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```